Looking for Additional Signal Protocol Attacks
I’m researching different types of attacks on the Signal protocol and have identified the following so far:

Unknown Key Share (UKS) Attack
Key Compromise Impersonation (KCI) Attack

I’m wondering if any of you know of other attacks that have been applied to the Signal protocol, along with relevant papers or references. Any contributions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!
